# Install .ipa on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, ipa

I uploaded my app.ipa to diawi.
When I install the app on iPhone 4s, 5s it works correctly.
When I install it on iPhone 6 with UDID which starts with FFFFFF.. it says can not install the application on this iPhone this time .
I found that these UDID's called fake .
How can I solve this .

Comment: you need to change the device udid to a correct one (look it up with device connected in itunes) in apple dev account and then recreate the correct provisioning profile

Comment: iOS7 (and upper) will give you a UDID starting with FFFF if you try to read it through code. You need to get them through iTunes/XCode, etc.

Comment: @imanabumazen why jailbreak? you just need an apple dev subscription

Comment: Just copy the UDID from itunes and add this UDID in developer account-> Member Center->Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles->Devices. and add your udid and Name.

Comment: I used iTunes ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

This UDID is taken using What's my UDID like apps which are not returning correct UDIDs after iOS7.

You may open this link http://get.udid.io/ on your device browser to get correct UDID.

Comment: I used this link and it returned fake UDID's . I used iTunes instead . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 7, the API that returns your device's UDID doesn't return the real UDID anymore. In order to retrieve your UDID, you must follow these steps:

1. Open iTunes
2. Connect your device
3. Select your device:

[image]

4. Select Summary Tab:

[image]

5. Click your serial number, and your UDID will appear:

[image]